# Disable JSplitPane divider listener temporarily

Tags: java, listener, jsplitpane

I have a simple JSplitPane which has listener on resize and listener on movement of divider. I need to set the divider location in resize listener without the divider listener printing out "foo", but this code with `boolean listener`doesn't seem to solve the problem.

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            listener = false;
            setDividerLocation(lastDividerLocation);
            listener = true;
        }

    });
addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            if (listener) {
                System.out.println("foo");
            }
        }
    });
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

EDIT:
SSCCE

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

public class Split extends JSplitPane {

    private boolean listener = true;
    private double lastDividerLocation = 0.5;

    public Split() {
        this.setOrientation(VERTICAL_SPLIT);

        this.add(new JPanel(), JSplitPane.TOP);
        this.add(new JPanel(), JSplitPane.BOTTOM);

        this.setDividerLocation(300);

        final PropertyChangeListener dividerListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                if (listener) {
                    if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL_SPLIT) {
                        lastDividerLocation = (double) getDividerLocation() / (double) getHeight();
                    } else if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL_SPLIT) {
                        lastDividerLocation = (double) getDividerLocation() / (double) getWidth();
                    }
                    System.out.println("divider: " + lastDividerLocation);
                }
            }
        };
        addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, dividerListener);

        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                listener = false;
                setDividerLocation(lastDividerLocation);
                listener = true;
            }

        });

        this.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.add(new Split(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it does not solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the propertyChangeListener?

Comment: @StephaneM When I resize the JSplitPane, it still prints out the "foo"

Comment: @SaviourSelf I don't really want to do that, it would be slow, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm curious if you're running into a synchronization issue. Can you post an SSCCE? I don't think it would be slow though.

Comment: I'm wondering, which event is fired first?

Comment: @SaviourSelf When resizing the window I need the dividerListener not to be invoked after calling method setDividerLocation.

Answer (score 1):

From what I experienced, this is one of the only two ways I found to make such thing. You either set a shared boolean, or you remove and add back the listener.

I would go more for removing the listener, it's safer, and it's not really that expensive an operation in my opinion (now I'll admit that if the event is sent so many times during a resize, it might not be ideal).

However, your solution will work too, as both events will occur on the Event Dispatch Thread, you shouldn't encounter concurrency issues. Make sure you don't change this boolean outside of this context, though.

---

Another interesting question in your case would be **why** do you need to set the last location back? What do you want to achieve exactly? Couldn't it be achieved with a proper value to [setResizeWeight()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setResizeWeight(double))?

Comment: I've attempted both of your suggestions and can't get either of them working. http://pastebin.com/RsH73sv0

Comment: I need the proportional location of the divider to stay exactly the same when resizing the frame. For example when I set the location 0.7 I want it to stay 0.7 no matter how the frame is resized.

Comment: @Glissinda - Try with setResizeWeight(0.5), it should keep the percentage between the two sides equal when you resize.

Comment: @Gnoupi - Even when I don't change the position of the divider and just resize with setResizeWeight(0.5), it keeps changing it's value. Also, I believe, that this wouldn't work, because when the divider would be 0.7, the coefficient should be 0.7 as well, right?

Comment: @Glissinda - Do not confuse setDividerLocation with setResizeWeight. The resize weight determine from which side space is taken or added when resizing. The default value is 0, so nothing happens on the left/top side. 0.5 will make both sides resize equally, no matter of the divider location. The coefficient should remain the same (as long as you don't go to extreme values, like reducing the size of the pane too much, in which case the coefficient is lost and resetting to the center position (but you have the same effect with your solution)

Comment: I must say, that I'm really surprised there's no simple way to have divider's proportional location the same, when resizing JSplitPane container.

Comment: @Gnoupi - I get the difference between setDividerLocation and setResizeWeight, but when I print the divider proportional location in resize listener, the coefficient is changing.. any idea why?

Comment: @Glissinda - I see that indeed. I assume it's due to rounding error when resizing. For example, if you resize and add an impair number of pixels, one side will get one more pixel, and it's easy to derive from there. Because the point of this method is not to keep the coefficient, but to add space according to a weight, so it is bound to be imperfect. It might not suit your needs because of that, indeed.